# Nested ItemsControl Orientation

Tags: wpf, nested, orientation, itemscontrol

I have a nested ItemsControl.  My data structure is an ObservableCollection of Campaigns which consist of a Campaign class and an observableCollection of Data counts (total, assigned, unassigned, closed).  What I need is the following:

```
CAMPAIGN.NAME
     TOTAL     UNASSIGNED     ASSIGNED     CLOSED
CAMPAIGN.NAME
     TOTAL     UNASSIGNED     ASSIGNED     CLOSED
```

I am able to get the first part of this, but for some reason it will not honor the orientation for the second ItemsControl.  What am I missing?  My XAML is:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icCampaignChicklets" ItemsSource="{Binding CampChicks}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="gridContent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="CampaignHeader" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=Campaign.Name}" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="icChicklets" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Width="150" Height="140" Background="{Binding Background}" Cursor="Hand"
                                    MouseLeftButtonDown="Chicklet_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                    >
                                        <Grid x:Name="gridContent" Margin="8,4">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountCaption, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White" FontSize="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="7" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="Ú" Foreground="#99ffffff" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3,5" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the orientation of the contents of an ItemsControl, set its `ItemsPanel` property like so:

```
<ItemsControl
    ...attributes...
    >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Wrapping it in a horizontally-oriented parent `StackPanel` will merely arrange it and its siblings horizontally, but in this particular case it has no siblings.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried that earlier, but Intellisense went nuts.  I must have had something else crazy at the time.